# Redirect USB audio output to the speaker | Guitar link interface

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, speakers, sound-card

If I connect my guitar directly to the line in and use Guitar Rig 5 with ASIO, it'll use the *Speakers (Realtek HD Audio)* output device exclusively, meaning that I won't be able to play sounds from any other app through that output device (it didn't use to be like that for Windows XP).

For this very reason I've bought a USB guitar link interface which gives me another output device that I could use only for playing guitar. My goal is to somehow redirect the output of that device to my speakers. Stereo mix is not picking up the sound from the **USB device**, only my **Speakers (Realtek HD)**.

How could I get the sound from that to my speakers so that I can play music and my guitar at the same time?

See the playback devices

[image]

And recording devices with stereo mix settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A software mixer like [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) allows you to set Guitar Rig 5 to output to a software AUX controlled by the mixer, then you can have the mixer mix the system audio with the Guitar Rig 5 output to your real audio output.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of for you to achieve this is to download something like Audacity, import the audio file that you want to play over into a track and assign your USB interface output to another. Set global output to Realtek HD Audio and If you hit play, the audio will start to playback and your guitar should be live trough your speakers.

Comment: This is still not what I was aiming for, but I'll give it a shot, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 sets of speakers or a device inserted between the PC and speakers that can blend the two outputs, such as a **2-channel mixer**.